# xgboost not found. xgboost conversion API is disabled error when trying to convert XGBoost model to Core ML model

Tags: python, xgboost, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to convert an XGBoost model to a Core ML model, I'm using **Google Colab** and here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
import coremltools as ct


data = pd.read_csv('/content/Rugby Position Requirements Updated - Rugby Position Requirements.csv')

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

data_copy = data.copy()

data_copy['Position_Numerical'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['Position'])
data = data_copy
data
features = ['Weight_KG', 'Height_CM', 'EBF', 'L_Run_S', '40m_Sprint_S', 'Speed_KMPH', 'Endurance', '1RM_Bench_Press_KG', 'Vertical_Jump_CM']
X = data[features].values

y = data.Position_Numerical

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 11)

train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = y_train)
test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label = y_test)

param = {
    'max_depth': 4,
    'eta': 0.3,
    'objective': 'multi:softmax',
    'num_class': 15 }
epochs = 10

xgb_model = xgb.train(param, train, epochs)

coreml_model = ct.converters.xgboost.convert(xgb_model)
coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

This is the whole error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-d5b7e2c517d7> in <module>()
      1 import coremltools as ct
      2 
----> 3 coreml_model = ct.converters.xgboost.convert(xgb_model)
      4 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/xgboost/_tree_ensemble.py in convert_tree_ensemble(model, feature_names, target, force_32bit_float, mode, class_labels, n_classes)
    151     """
    152     if not (_HAS_XGBOOST):
--> 153         raise RuntimeError("xgboost not found. xgboost conversion API is disabled.")
    154     accepted_modes = ["regressor", "classifier"]
    155     if mode not in accepted_modes:

RuntimeError: xgboost not found. xgboost conversion API is disabled.
```

I tried looking for a fix but no luck. How can I fix this issue?